# Shopify embedded app doesn't load in firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe, header, shopify, shopify-app

I've made a simple app with spring boot, postgres, docker and traefik.
I've registered my app into shopify as an embdeable app.
I've created a domain name for it, and setup https.

But when loading my app on firefox from shopify demo store with firefox I face the following error message [image: screen grab]

But when using chrome the same app load.

I've defined a csp as described in shopify documentation to allow the admin app and my demo store to embed the app.

On the network tab of the devtools, I see one request that failes which says:

[image: firefox issue]

This leads me to think that I should define a X-Frame-Options header. But mdn docs says that this headers was replaced by CSP header for my use case.

I'm not looking for answer with this kind of question, but for advice on where should I be paying attention.

I should also mention that I'm using app-bridge.

After playing a bit more I ended up try to use the "Ignore X-Frame-Options" firefox extension. This ended up fixing the issue.
But as I understand this x-frame-options that's causing my problem is not on my backend, but rather on one of shopify service (accounts.shopify.com)

It's unclear to me what should be the next step.

Comment: You are presumably a paying customer of Shopify, did you ask their support?

Comment: No I'm not a paying customer of shopify.
Plus since the documentation is deficient on that particular front, I hope WE can leave a trace to help others trying to build an app that should embed into shopify